# Why is my image clipped after scaling?

Tags: android-layout, imageview, scrollview, android-imageview

I am having a strange problem. I scale an image and, while scaling works correctly, the image always gets clipped. I tried different scale types - things changed but I never could make it work.

Just to be clear, here's what I need to solve:
1. I have a `HorizontalScrollView` around the `ImageView` and a `ScrollView` around the `HorizontalView`.
2. I scroll around (using `scrollTo` of both scroll views) and, upon a certain event, zoom in.
3. What I'd like to happen is for the `ImageView` to scale around my current scroll position.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And here's the scaling code (`originalWidth`/`originalHeight` are calculated at scale of `1`; `targetView` points to the `ImageView`):

```
public synchronized void changeScale(float newScaleFactor) {
    this.scaleFactor = Math.max(min_zoom, Math.min(newScaleFactor, max_zoom));
    if (targetView != null && originalWidth > 0) {
        int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * scaleFactor);
        int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * scaleFactor);
        onScaleChanged(targetView, scaleFactor, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
}


public void onScaleChanged(View targetView, float scaleFactor, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = targetView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = newWidth;
    layoutParams.height = newHeight;

    // This is needed to increase the pane size (rather than zoom within the initial layout)
    targetView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    // Tell the system to recalculate the layout
    targetView.requestLayout();

    // This is needed to specify the center of scaling
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)targetView.getParent();
    ScrollView vertScrollView = (ScrollView)horizontalScrollView.getParent();
    // ~~~ the pivot points are probably wrong 
    targetView.setPivotX(horizontalScrollView.getScrollX() * scaleFactor);
    targetView.setPivotY(vertScrollView.getScrollY() * scaleFactor);

    // This is needed for actual zooming
    targetView.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
    targetView.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
};


public void zoomIn(float scaleDelta) {
    changeScale(scaleFactor + scaleDelta);
}

public void zoomOut(float scaleDelta) {
    changeScale(scaleFactor - scaleDelta);
}
```

Question 1: How do I prevent clipping? I can't find the right combination of `scaleType` and layout resizing.

Question 2: When I use `setScaleX`/`setScaleY`, should my pivot be calculated after applying the new scale factor or does the renderer take care of that automatically?

Comment: seems to me like you should be verifying that the values you are setting for your image size are within the bounds of the screen.  I imagine that one is set properly but the other one overflows.

Comment: My image is within a ScrollView. It can be of any size I wish. The clipping I complain about is that of scrollview limiting where I scroll

Comment: To further elaborate, my problem is almost identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963866/how-to-change-size-of-android-scrollview. The only difference is that I scale the ScrollView's child whereas that guy changes the child altogether.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the scale you need to invalidate(), and requestLayout() the views.

```
targetView.invalidate();
targetView.requestLayout();
```

I usually calculate the scale differently for images. You could try to scale the image view using the MATRIX scale type. You will need to know the size of your bound DPI.

```
// Get the scaled DPI
int boundBoxInDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * scaleFactor

// Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
// closer to its side. This way the image always stays inside your
// bound AND either x/y axis touches the bound but neither will go over.
float xScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / newWidth;
float yScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / newHeight;
float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

// scale using our calculated scale
targetView.setScaleX(scale);
targetView.setScaleY(scale);
```

As to your second question about the Pivot. That will probably need to be set to the center of the visible scroll area. The the scrollable area should be increased when you change the image size since you are using `FIT_CENTER`;

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=723) for code that works quite well. I ditched my HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView and attached this PanAndZoomListener to my FrameLayout and from then on it was all rainbows and unicorns.

I tried to do the same thing as you, but without success. It would seem that you can scroll an ImageView without using HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView. I'm still unclear as to what makes it happen, but I'm leaning toward the use of the image matrix (as in, setImageMatrix on ImageView) or possibly the use of MarginLayoutParams. In looking at the Gallery source code from the picture Gallery available on the Android, I'm seeing heavy use of Matrix. Unfortunately, the documentation on this seems to be quite light in my estimation.

Other people have figured it out, so plug in the PanAndZoomListener and you're done. That's what I did.